# Excel Insert text depending on answer

Tags: excel, list, if-statement, drop-down-menu

I have an excelsheet with dropdown answer from cell D8 and down in D. The choices are "Medium", "High", and "Very high". Im trying to figure out a way to do the following:

> 1) If D8 is medium leave the cell N8 empty
>   2) If D8 is High then
>   write irrelevant in N8
>   3) If D8 is Very High then write "Call Person
>   on phoneXXX" in N8

I have tried to use a normal IF statement, but I can't find a way to leave the cell empty if D8 is Medium so I have a feeling that privatesub is the way to go.

Comment: I knew I answered similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48949480/add-many-ifs-to-a-formula

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
=IF(D8="Medium","",IF(D8="High","irrelevant",IF(D8="Very High","Call person on phoneXXX","none of the above")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MATCH in conjunction with INDEX or CHOOSE:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX({"","Irrelevant","Call Person on phoneXXX"},MATCH(LEFT(N8),{"M","H","V"},0)),"Not Listed")
```

OR

```
=IFERROR(CHOOSE(MATCH(LEFT(N8),{"M","H","V"},0),"","Irrelevant","Call Person on phoneXXX"),"Not Listed)
```

Another choice, If you have Office 365 Excel is IFS():

```
=IFERROR(IFS(LEFT(N8)="M","",LEFT(N8)="H","Irrelevant",LEFT(N8),"Call Person on phoneXXX"),"Not Listed")
```